# post to "me" wall after getting signed_request

Tags: facebook, user-permissions

Having obtained signed_request from facebook through registration plugin, what is the code for posting to a user's wall? Normally I would use

```
 $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'Testing posting to my wall', 'cb' => ''));
```

but as I am using the php example at the buttom of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ I am not using

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId'  => APP_ID,
 'secret' => APP_SECRET
 ));
```

Including 'facebook.php' cause the error

```
 Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```